# Youtube videos placed in transparent div are transparent as well

Tags: css, youtube, opacity

I'm placing a youtube iframe in a content box that has 0.8 opacity

```
opacity: .8;
filter: alpha(opacity=80);
```

but the videos are showing transparent as well, as in you can see the background of the site through them. I've tried changing wmode every way possible but it makes no difference. This doesn't happen with Firefox, but it does in Chrome.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you use the CSS property `opacity` on an element, all of its children will inherit it, and there is nothing you do to change it...

...except you can either use a transparent png background image, or use `rgba()` or `hsla()` color values.

So transparent black rgba would be `background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);` and hsla `background-color: hsla(0, 0%, 0%, .5);`

These properties are not inherited and so will not affect the children, whatever they are :)

Here you can see the three different CSS rules (not transparent png) in use. Note that the child elements of the last two are not affected :)

http://jsfiddle.net/SJK2H/

Answer (score 2):

Actually, that's how `opacity` is supposed to work, it sets the opacity on the element and all its contents, not just the background. If you just want a semi-transparent background, you should use something like a transparent png as a `background-image`.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest using semi-transparent .png as background instead of opacity.
You can also use rgba as background color, but it is not implemented in IE. Rgba is not supported in IE 8 and below (not sure for IE 9) so desired effect could be achieved using filters instead. 
But it sometimes somehow makes fonts look terrible (removes anti-aliasing or smth. of that sort).

On the other hand, png of 1*1px is really small and can be built into your css-file.